# Why cold swap is affected by API level while hot swap isn't in Android Instant Run?

Tags: android, android-instant-run

Recently I read an article about how Instant Run in Android Studio works.
https://medium.com/google-developers/instant-run-how-does-it-work-294a1633367f

I think I got the most of the article, but I couldn't understand why only cold swap is affected by API level while hot swap isn't. (or vice versa)
I'm curious what’s the difference between hot swap and cold swap when it comes to the way of replacing dex files, because I think hot swap also needs the capability of replacing multiple dex.